# Editor navigation via ctrl+arrow does not work after tweak tool 'show location of pointer' was on

Tags: gnome, keyboard, text-editor, gnome-tweak-tool

the title says it all, after downloading the **gnome tweak tool** and switching the 'show location of pointer' option to *on*, and then turning it *off* again after several days, the navigation using control and any of the arrow keys in text-editors (gedit, texmaker) does not work anymore (jumping to the next word, marking lines using ctrl+shift+arrow works fine, but only with horizontal arrows.

It did not work when the option was *on* either. Editors in VM work fine after it had been turned *off* again.

Is there any way to fix this? Does anyone know where to find the answer? The machine is running ubuntu 16.04.; not sure what further information could help...?

Thanks a lot in prior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a fresh install did the job... i am very new to ubuntu, but very interested in the possibilities. gnome tweak tool is nothing for me, changes too much too deep from my perspective. what i wanted it to do in the first place was show the location of the pointer, of course the preset shortcuts i got used to where then messed up as well (left ctrl).